I want to display a notification in editor when user saves a post , when certain criteria are met
So far I have this action added on pre_post_update, 10, 3
public function check1($post_id, $data){
    if (1==1) {
        set_transient('1_is_1'. $post_id, true, 30);
    }
    return $data;
}

and then I have this action added to admin_notices:
public function display_1_is_1_warning() {
    global $post;

    if (isset($post->ID) && get_transient('1_is_1' . $post->ID)) {
        echo '<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
                <p>1 is 1</p>
              </div>';

        delete_transient('1_is_1' . $post->ID);
    }
}

The HTML of the notice is appended and I can see it's inside a div with classes wrap hide-if-js block-editor-no-js and it's hidden. Is there something I need to do on the JS side to make it appear?

on my test site, I don't have this wrapper which hide the notice. maybe it's another plugin which interfere with your notice.

You can try the given approach to achieve the desired results. Here is the update code you need to use.
/**
* This is the action to check a condition before the post is updated.
*/
add_action( 'pre_post_update', 'check1', 10, 2 );
function check1( $post_id, $data ) {
    if (1 == 1) {
        set_transient('1_is_1' . $post_id, true, 30);
    }
    return $data;
}

/** 
* This is the action to display the notice in the admin area.
*/
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'display_1_is_1_warning' );
function display_1_is_1_warning() {
    global $post;

    if ( isset( $post->ID ) && get_transient( '1_is_1' . $post->ID ) ) {
        echo '<div id="1_is_1_notice" class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
                <p>1 is 1</p>
              </div>';
        delete_transient( '1_is_1' . $post->ID );
    }
}


/**
* This is to enqueue JavaScript file to handle the display of the notice.
*/
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_admin_script' );
function enqueue_custom_admin_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-admin-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-admin.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
}

This is the JS Code which we need to added to /js/custom-admin.js file.

jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // Ensure the notice is displayed
    var notice = $( '#1_is_1_notice' );
    if ( notice.length ) {
        notice.closest( '.wrap, .hide-if-js, .block-editor-no-js' ).removeClass( 'hide-if-js block-editor-no-js' );
        notice.show();
    }
});


these are the APIs to use for notices, PHP and JS, depending on where you want them to be displayed https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/notices/
